# Quickblox (Q-municate)Firebase Authentication error

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android, q-municate

When I test the `Q-municate Quickblox Android API` after including a test Phone number in `firebase console` authentication it works fine.
However, when I am trying another number which is not included in the `Firebase` console authentication, it displays the following error:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please Verify the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the firebase console

Note: This is working fine with a test phone number and I proved that the `Sha-1` Key & `firebase` Project package name are OK.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please Verify the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the firebase console"

Comment: @MaxvonHippel , I have checked everything a number of times but everything ok, SHA-1 key and Firebase Configurations

Comment: @MaxvonHippel  Have You got what type of problem I am Facing?